# Watching for changes in $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, web-applications, firebase-realtime-database

Below is the code I use to bring the selected players from my firebase databse to my scope:

```
 var orderedPlayers = databaseService.players.orderByChild("id");
$firebaseArray(orderedPlayers)
        .$loaded(function(loadedPlayers) {
        var normalizedPlayers = loadedPlayers.reduce(function(acc, next) { acc[next.id] = next; return acc; }, {});
        var selectedPlayers = $scope.pick.map(function(num){
            return normalizedPlayers[num];
        });
        $scope.players = selectedPlayers;

        $scope.sum =function(items, prop){
        return items.reduce (function(a, b) {
        return a + b [prop];
        }, 0);
        }; 
        $scope.totalPoints = $scope.sum($scope.players, 'goals');    


}, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    $scope.players = [];
});
```

The problem is that when I change the number of goals from the firebase database, there is no real time change of the total nuber of points. i.e.  `$scope.players = selectedPlayers;` updates in real time but `$scope.totalPoints only` updates after refreshing the page.

Is it possible to have the latter update in real time as well?

Comment: Show your *html* template code.

Comment: Show some more code or create a fiddle to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Is the code snippet you have posted, part of a single method, or is it just the entire codeblock for $onInit() for example? If this code above is in one method, and called from somewhere it might show why the error is occurring (for example $firebaseArray only being called when the method is called).

Comment: can you update your question with $scope.sum method, so that I can help you.

Comment: @MuruGan I just did thanks

Comment: Sounds, Great. Your Welcome

Comment: @MuruGan i edited the $scope.sum  function in

Comment: @Deji Caleb Awoniyi. I am working on it. can you please tell me. what is in the scope.players. i.e what values are there. can you show me a screen shot of it?

Comment: @MuruGan scope.players is just an array of objects that have ids that match the numbers in the array called scope.pick.

Answer (score 0):

why to not just set it in the call back directly to be

```
$scope.players  = $scope.pick.map(function(num){ ...
```

rather than

```
var selectedPlayers = $scope.pick.map(function(num){
```

this will bind the results directly into the scope variable

Comment: thanks but this still did not work. When I changed the player goals in the firebase databse, there was no  change in the sum total until i refreshed the page.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

- Angular 1.x.x
- `$scope.totalPoints` is a number (primitive)

It could be that `$scope.totalPoints` is being used by a child scope (maybe a nested directive or controller) and that is why the change did not get propagated to them. Try wrapping `totalPoints` inside and object.

```
$scope.state = {
  totalPoints: 0
};
```

Make the required changes in the template and firebase callback.

If that doesn't work try manually requesting a digest cycle using

```
$scope.$apply(function () {
  $scope.totalPoints = $scope.sum($scope.players, 'goals'); 
})
```